# Making an Inventory list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a way to input data through the top row and in return that data be saved in secondary cells below.  Here is my application:

I am making an inventory list.
Lets assume I have 5 products:

- vaccine
- dewormer
- identification tags
- service work
- laboratory test

and I have listed these products in cells A2 through A6.  In cell A1, I want to select one of these products (using data validation and making a list of my 5 products I have listed in cells A2-A6).

In cell B11, I will input a number that will specify how many of the product I've ordered.
Next, starting in cell B2, I will allocate a rule: (NOTE: A2 has "vaccine" inputted into it)

> IF(A1=A2;B2="vaccine";0)

and I will continue this rule down the column (A1=B3,dewormer,A1=B4,Identification tags, etc) and so on through my list.
In doing this, it will allow the row where the product I am dealing with to be active for further applications.

However, Here is where I am having trouble.
Now that I have my initial argument, I want to use cell B1 to input an order number that will be transferred into the corresponding number in column C.

> I want to make the argument stand that
>   IF B2=A2
>      then
>      C2=B1

Thus, if I select "vaccine" in cell A1, and then in B1 I type the number 5 (indicating that I ordered 5 vaccines) that data is to be inputted in cell C2 below).

But now I want that '5' to be saved so if I move on to continue inputting the rest of my data the 5 is not lost from cell C2.  Currently I can tie them together but if I move on to another product, that 5 is no longer a valid argument and is deleted. Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Definitely need to include a screenshot of your table. Too much text for someone to read and piece together

Comment: You will need to use VBA in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for Access !